# The imported modle's textures doesn't load in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, assets

I have been struggling with this for about two days now and by the articles I have read, it hasn't been only me. Basically, when I import a module, which I have downloaded from the Internet, it comes with the module itself and it's textures.

Once I import everything, the module is pure white as it doesn't have any textures. I have tried a few solutions which I found in stackoverflow, in unity's site and YouTube, but nothing seemed to work.

The most common solution was to change the Materials' location to "Use External Materials", but that only creates a folder with material, with colors, which doesn't match the original ones.
[image]
[image]

Here is an image of the problem as well:
[image]

EDIT:
I found the solution, not sure if the comments meant to tell me to do that, but in the end I found it on my own. Basically, you have to click on the texture (in the unity assets), go to the Materials tab and click "Extract Textures", then just choose the folder that your projects is in (so the folder that Unity already suggested) and click OK!
[image]

Comment: I think you're just missing a material. If your asset isn't made for unity, it won't come with materials. You should create two materials and add the textures as base textures.

Comment: Simply reference the textures again in the according materials `Albedo` / `MainTexture` is usually the main texture and then you have a normal map you drag into the materials `Normal` slot, I assume the other might be a specular map also drag into according slot  .. done

Comment: @derHugo Could you find me an article or something similar as have no clue how to do it? I tried searching for it but I don't really know what I am searching for.

Comment: @repinSlun Put all the textures in the fbx file and then import it into the project. If it doesn't work, extract the materials, adjust the maps, model and apply it.

Comment: I believe there is a button that extracts the textures for this purpose, either on the model or the material (can't fully remember)? EDIT: oops... didn't finish reading! Glad you found the solution, it was right under your nose

Comment: If this model was created with Blender and materials there were created with the Nodes system, most likely, the import into Unity will be faulty. There's no proper export of Nodes materials into fbx that can be understood by Unity, so you usually end up recreating the materials in Unity anyhow.